# Swipe slide and move imageView position

Tags: ios, swift

in my code some time it increases a lot and some time let the image position increase and decrease.

```
IBOutlet weak var bgImage: UIImageView! 
IBOutlet weak var sliders: UISlider! 
IBOutlet weak var imgViews: UIImageView! 
var location = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) 
var valueOFButterFly = 54.5 
var lastValueOfSlider = Float()

@IBAction func sliderValue(_ sender: UISlider) {
    print(sender.value)


    if lastValueOfSlider >= sender.value {

        valueOFButterFly = valueOFButterFly - 1
         print("new value \(valueOFButterFly)")
        imgViews.center = CGPoint(x: valueOFButterFly, y: 81.5)

    }
    else if (lastValueOfSlider < sender.value) {

        valueOFButterFly = valueOFButterFly + 1
        print("new value \(valueOFButterFly)")
        imgViews.center = CGPoint(x: valueOFButterFly, y: 81.5)

    }
    else {
        print("else if")
    }
    self.lastValueOfSlider = sender.value
}
```

Comment: IBOutlet weak var bgImage: UIImageView!
    IBOutlet weak var sliders: UISlider!
    IBOutlet weak var imgViews: UIImageView!
    var location = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    var valueOFButterFly = 54.5
    var lastValueOfSlider = Float()

Comment: That depends upon the min and max value of your slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to match the `imageView's centre` with that of the `slider value`, you need to set the `slider's currentValue` as `imageView's centre` instead of `incrementing or decrementing by 1`.

Also, update the `imageView.center` in `valueOFButterFly's` `didSet property observer` instead of updating it multiple times throughout the code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!

    var lastValueOfSlider = Float()

    var valueOFButterFly = 54.5 {
        didSet {
            imageView.center = CGPoint(x: self.valueOFButterFly, y: 81.5)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        slider.minimumValue = 0
        slider.maximumValue = Float(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        imageView.center = CGPoint(x: self.valueOFButterFly, y: 81.5)
    }

    @IBAction func sliderValue(_ sender: UISlider) {
        print(sender.value)
        valueOFButterFly = Double(sender.value)
        self.lastValueOfSlider = sender.value
    }
}
```

In the above code, I've used

1. `slider.minimumValue = 0`
2. `slider.maximumValue = Float(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)`

You can configure the above properties as per your requirement.